# What is the relation between expressive completeness and semantic completeness

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic

A formal system is expressively complete if and only if it is capable of expressing, as a formula, everything that is the subject of that formal system.

A deductive system is semantically complete if and only if every sentence that is truth-functionally entailed by a set of sentences can be derived from that set.

Is there a relation between these two types of completeness?
If the two are related, what type of relation is this?

Comment: Maybe useful : [Expressive Completeness and Completeness](http://www.cogsci.rpi.edu/~heuveb/teaching/Logic/CompLogic/Web/Presentations/Propositional%20Logic%20More%20Algebra.pdf).

Comment: In a nutshell: yes and no. If the set of connectives is **not** adequate (i.e. it cannot generate all truth-functions) we will have some truth-function that is "identically true" that is not expressible. But the issue is that if it is not expressible in the language it is also not *provable*.

Comment: But if we consider non-trivial example, like [Implicational propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicational_propositional_calculus) with only **→** as connective, suitbale axioms and *modus ponens*, we have that it is [*complete* with respect to standard semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicational_propositional_calculus#Completeness), i.e. it proves all the tautologies containing only **→**.

Comment: Say there is a (non-classical) system intended to have expressive power and is thereby presumably intended to be expressively complete.  Is it possible at all to infer anything as to its semantic completeness from this expressive completeness?

Any texts concerning this relation will be much appreciated.